# Preventing Out-Of-Bounds in kepler: branches, textures or bigger buffers?

Tags: cuda, gpgpu

could someone tell me the gain in performance if I use read-only cache memory (kepler) instead of a texture ?

I have a design decision here, protecting out-of-bounds acceses:

a) put some branches. Check if the access will be OOB and avoid it.

b) using textures for adressing mode (border).

c) allocate bigger buffers...

what option would yield better performance?

Comment: Do you imagine there is a single, constant and uniform performance gain across every application? The only relevant answer to you is obtained by benchmarking your code (or at least a model of your use case). And the answer you get isn't going to be very relevant to anyone else. Sorry, but I am voting to close this.

Comment: I dont think so, but it could be some "best practices" or rule of thumbs for this new architecture... for example: "dont use texture only for addressing purposes"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will probably have to code up both versions a) and b) and benchmark them against each other.

It is difficult to assess in general how the peculiarities of textures, like

- floating point coordinates potentially requiring additional type conversions
- fixed register layout for texture instructions potentially increasing register pressure

score against their advantage of zero(-additional)-cycle bounds checking.

My general expectation would however be that both will be quite close together. Above mentioned (dis-) advantages more or less cancel each other, and the difference will be tiny compared to the latency of global memory access.